# Mails sent from django code are not showing up in IMAP "sent" folder

Tags: python, django, smtp, imap, postfix-mta

I use Django's [send_mail()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail) method for sending emails via my own mail server (a typical Linux mail stack). When using Gmail as the SMTP server, every sent message is given the "Sent" IMAP label and is viewable in the sent folder afterwards. How can I implement the same functionality in my own setup?

I know this is a special feature of Gmail, and probably I should be using the `imap_append` function after sending the mail for putting it in sent folder, but I'm not sure how this can be done in code. For example, the send_mail function doesn't return sent message's `message-id`. Are there any code samples available for this in Django or even other languages? As far as I checked, other languages don't do this by default either.

Or if it is easier to implement by configuring the mail server, how can I configure my mail server's SMTP (Linux postfix-dovecot) to apply "Sent" label to any outgoing message?

Comment: Add the message-id header yourself, then use imap_append. By the way, labels are not an IMAP concept, it has folders.